# How to use CustomAdapter with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I am Trying to Display the `IP Address` in a `ListView`.I created a `ListAdapter` & `ArrayAdapter` but it is not displaying properly.So I think i need a CustomAdapter to Display the Addresses.I have already Used `TextView` to display it.I need the Adapter to display the values which are displayed in the TextView.

So Help me in the Right Direction :)

Thanks for your Help ...

**connect.java**

```
public class connect extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{
WifiApManager wifiApManager;
TextView tv;
Button ipscan;
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptv);
    ipscan=(Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
    ipscan.setOnClickListener(this);  
lv = getListView();


}
class scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ClientScanResult>>{ 
    public Context context;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients= new  ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
    public scan(Context c)  // constructor to take Context
    {
        context = c;   // Initialize your Context variable
    }

    protected ArrayList<ClientScanResult> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
        return wifiApManager.getClientList(false);

    }

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients){
    ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult>(connect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clients);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
    tv.append("Clients: \n");
for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) 
    {

        //tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
        // tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
       // tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
       // tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
    }
}
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Click Action...
    scan myScan = new scan(this); // pass the context to the constructor
    myScan.execute();
}
}
```

ClientScanResult.java

```
public class ClientScanResult { 
private String IpAddr; 

private String HWAddr; 

private String Device; 

private boolean isReachable; 

public ClientScanResult(String ipAddr, String hWAddr, String device, boolean isReachable) { 
super(); 
IpAddr = ipAddr; 
HWAddr = hWAddr; 
Device = device; 
this.setReachable(isReachable); 
} 

@Override 
public String toString() { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
return this.IpAddr.toString(); 
} 

public String getIpAddr() { 
return IpAddr; 
} 




public void setIpAddr(String ipAddr) { 
IpAddr = ipAddr; 
} 

public String getHWAddr() { 
return HWAddr; 
} 

public void setHWAddr(String hWAddr) { 
HWAddr = hWAddr; 
} 

public String getDevice() { 
return Device; 
} 

public void setDevice(String device) { 
Device = device; 
} 

public void setReachable(boolean isReachable) { 
this.isReachable = isReachable; 
} 

public boolean isReachable() { 
return isReachable; 
} 
}
```

NOTE:
I Commented the Lines which i used to display the values in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the arraylist clients and use the same in CustomAdapter.

In `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`

```
 CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this,clients);
 lv.setAdapter(cus);
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAarrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
LayoutInflater mInflater;
List<ClientScanResult> resultList;
public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List<ClientScanResult> list)
{
   super(context,0,list);
   resultList = list;
   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
ViewHolder holder; 

if (convertView == null) { 
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
// inflate custom layout called row 
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.tv =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
holder.tv1 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
holder.tv2 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
// initialize textview
convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
      holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
      ClientScanResult result = (ClientScanResult)resultList.get(position);
      holder.tv.setText(result.getIpAddr());  
      holder.tv1.setText(result.getDevice()); 
      holder.tv2.setText(result.getHWAddr()); 
      // set the name to the text;

return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder
{

   TextView tv,tv1,tv2;
} 
}
```

Create row.xml with 3 textviews with id textView1,textView2 and textView3

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListView3Activity extends ListActivity {

    ListView listView;
    static final String[] COUNTRIES = {"Argentina",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bangladesh",
    "China",
    "Denmark",
    "France",
    "Egypt",
    "Germany",
    "Hong Kong",
    "Iceland",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iraq",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Malaysia",
    "New Zealand",
    "Pakistan",
    "Singapore",
    "United States"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listView = getListView();

        //Own row layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can take idea from this code..i think its pretty simple..tell me if you have any doubt in this code.

Comment: As Arul said in question that he just want to show IP address in a ListView then in this case he does not need any customAdapter..:-)